# Simple GUI app with C backend

Tags: c, user-interface

I want to write a simple GUI application on a Linux machine (a few buttons, and a message display area), to use with a C back-end.
The C back-end code already exists, and I don't want to change it much.

What would be my best bet for the front-end?

Initially I thought I would use Ruby (e.g. using Shoes or Ruby on Rails), but I was wondering if I would end up spending too much time just making my front-end talk properly with my C back-end.

Would GTK+ be a better option to use instead?
Is there anything else you would suggest?

I would have to spend a considerable amount of time on making the front-end, regardless of what I go for.

Comment: If you choose GTK+ after all,I would advise you to use Glade designer,even though you have only a few controls.

Comment: Thanks everyone for all your suggestions! I played around with 'qtcreator' & 'shoes', and read up on 'wxPython'; but then realised that all these are way too powerful for my simple needs.
Finally I could do a pretty good job (much better than I had expected) using just glade.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest python, with either [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/) or [PyQT](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro)/[PySide](http://www.pyside.org/).
For communication with the C backend, you can use [`ctypes`](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html).

Here's an example of how C functions can be used with `ctypes`, from the documentation.

```
>>> printf = libc.printf
>>> printf("Hello, %s\n", "World!")
Hello, World!
>>> printf("Hello, %S\n", u"World!")
Hello, World!
>>> printf("%d bottles of beer\n", 42)
42 bottles of beer
>>> printf("%f bottles of beer\n", 42.5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
ArgumentError: argument 2: exceptions.TypeError: Don't know how to convert parameter 2
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what kind of input/output the back-end handles, consider using a socket or pipe for communication using a simple plaintext protocol. That way you can essentially use any programming language with basic file IO for the front-end, without much added hassle.

I would personally probably use Python, or Flash/AIR (because that's where my main expertise lies as far as GUI programming goes) and a socket connection to the back-end (running locally or remotely). But whatever you are more comfortable with will likely work too.